# Check entry based on entry in another column

Tags: sql-server

Still fairly new to databases and SQL, so bear with me. I'm trying to check whether or not data can be inserted depending on data in another column,

```
create table Table1
       (PaymentType varchar(5) not null
       check (PaymentType = 'CC' or PaymentType = 'PO' or PaymentType = 'Check'),
       CCNumber varchar(16)
       check (PaymentType = 'CC' and (LEN(CCNumber) = 15 or LEN(CCNumber) = 16) ),
       PONumber varchar(30)
       check (PaymentType = 'PO'),
       CheckNumber varchar(10)
       check (PaymentType = 'Check') );
```

This probably isn't the way to go about it, but I want `CCNumber` to accept data if `PaymentType` is `'CC'`, `PONumber` if `PaymentType` is `'PO'`, etc. How would I create those checks or constraints properly?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be a check constraint, but this will not give meaningful error messages

```
create table Table1
 (PaymentType varchar(5) not null,
 CCNumber varchar(16),
 PONumber varchar(30),
 CheckNumber varchar(10));
 GO
 ALTER Table Table1
 add CONSTRAINT CHK_PAYMENTTYPE CHECK 
  (CASE WHEN PaymentType = 'CC' and CCNumber is NOT NULL and PONumber is NULL and CheckNumber is NULL THEN 0
    WHEN PaymentType = 'PO' AND PONumber IS NOT NULL and CCNumber IS NULL and CheckNumber is NULL THEN 0
    WHEN PaymentType = 'Check' AND CheckNumber IS NOT NULL and CCNumber IS NULL and PONumber is NULL THEN 0
    ELSE 1 END = 0);
```

It would probably be better to do a foreign key relationship or just have a single column for the number with a check constraint that checks that the number is of correct format for each payment type

ps: dont store CreditCard numbers unencrypted in a database...

Answer (score 0):

You should most likly look into "modeling XOR" relationships as Table1 represents one of three payment types. These are never any fun.

PaymentSource is the base with a 1 to 0..1 relationship with each detail.

```
-- MSSQL 2005+ 
CREATE TABLE dbo.PaymentSource
(
    -- look into a squence if availiable 
    ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, 

    -- if a person needs to recognize the payment info for repeat use
    NickName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT('Default Account') 

    -- would likely have more info
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.PaymentSourceCC
(
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    CCNumber VARCHAR(15) CHECK (LEN(ccNumber) >15), -- column def takes care of the otherside
    CONSTRAINT baseCC FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES dbo.PaymentSource(ID)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.PaymentSourcePO
(
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    PONumber VARCHAR(30),
    CONSTRAINT basePO FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES dbo.PaymentSource(ID)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.PaymentSourceCheck
(
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    CheckNumber VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT baseCheck FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES dbo.PaymentSource(ID)
);

CREATE VIEW dbo.PaymentSource AS 
    SELECT
        ID,
        'CC' AS PaymentType
        CCNumber,
        NULL AS PONumber,
        NULL AS CheckNumber
    FROM PaymentSourceCC
UNION ALL
    SELECT
        ID,
        'PO' AS PaymentType
        NULL AS CCNumber,
        PONumber,
        NULL AS CheckNumber
    FROM PaymentSourceCC
UNION ALL
    SELECT
        ID,
        'Check' AS PaymentType
        NULL AS CCNumber,
        NULL AS PONumber,
        CheckNumber
    FROM PaymentSourceCC

-- add insert trigger to complete solution according to business rules
-- inserts one record to one and only one detail table
```

Comment: Careful; you need to add a PaymentSourceType column to PaymentSource that specifies if it's a CC, PO, Check, etc., and include it as part of the foreign key from the three other tables. Otherwise you could have a row in all four of those tables for a single PaymentSource. In the PaymentSourceCC table, for example, you'd have a PaymentSourceType `char(2)` column that is constrained to contain "CC".

Comment: Thank you you're right the implementation is naive. There currently is no way for the trigger to sort the rows. I missed that in my haste.